# How to get Contact Id provided an email address

Tags: contact, salesforce-id

I would like to perform some operations on Contact using the corresponding REST api. So, I need the contact Id. However, I would like to retrieve the contact id from the given email address. Is it possible? Can any one suggest me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could do something like this:

```
curl https://<your url>/services/data/<your api version>/query/?q=select+id+from+contact+where+email+%3d+<your email address> -H "Authorization: Bearer token"
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
curl https://<your url>/services/data/<your api version>/query/?q=select+id+from+contact+where+email+%3d+%27<your email address>%27 -H "Authorization: Bearer token"
```

Comment: Hi, how is this different or improve on the accepted answer?

Comment: @nbrown This answers includes the quote marks (%27). I'd consider it more of a comment than a new answer but it is useful